# JENKINS: Where is the data for previous builds for plot plugin stored?

Tags: jenkins, plot, plugins

The plot plugin in Jenkins plots the data point for not only the current build but also the previous ones. In fact, it also has an option *keepRecords* that keeps records for the builds that were deleted. Where are all these data points stored given that I clear the previous workspace at the start of the build? I need to know that so I can reliably store my performance numbers from the perf tests that run on each build.

Comment: For now, I am thinking of storing the performance numbers on version control.

Answer (score 0):

From the [plugin wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plot+Plugin):
`csvFileName (string, default: "$ROOT_DIR/plot-XXXX.csv") The name of the CSV file that persists the plots data. The CSV file is stored in the projects root directory. This is different from the source CSVle that can be used as a source for the plot.`

However, I don't see the `csvFileName` in root directory either. I do see the `CSVle` file in the root of the workspace directory.

Comment: This plot--XXX.csv is created in Job folder. If you have Jenkins server on Mac, it would be inside /.jenkins/jobs/<JOB-NAME> folder

Comment: Aha, so this CSV file is stored on the jenkins server file system. I don't think by default there's any ways for normal jenkins users to access this from the web UI -- you'd need remote login permission.